# How to chain quesrysets in the right order not sorted by date, sorted by foreignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I am building a photo gallery, and the ones that are published don't give me what i need so i am building it form scratch.

In the index page i need to get random albums (this is fine) from the Album model and for each album to bring one of its photos (`random`) from the Photo model.

Models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('כותרת', max_length=100, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField('תאריך פרסום', auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='galleries_creator', verbose_name='נכתב ע"י')

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('כותרת', max_length=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, verbose_name='שייך לאלבום')
    photo = models.ImageField('תמונה', blank=True, upload_to=get_image_path)
    photo_mid = models.ImageField('תמונה בינונית', blank=True, upload_to='images/galleries/mid/', editable=False)
    photo_thumb = models.ImageField('תמונה קטנה', blank=True, upload_to='images/galleries/thumbs/', editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('תאריך פרסום', auto_now_add=True)
    is_landscape = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name='האם תמונת לנדסקייפ', editable=False)
```

The thing is, as i see it, that in order to iterate over the albums in the template and get the correct photo for the album, i need to chain the list of albums and the list of photos i got, but in the right order (`album object, photo object etc`), but what i am getting is all the albums and then all the photos (in the right order, but in the template nothing is working, obvious).

View:

```
def index(request):
    albums = Album.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]
    album_photo_lst = []
    for album in albums:
        album_photo_lst.append(Photo.objects.filter(album=album).order_by('?')[:1])
    album_list = list(chain(albums,album_photo_lst))
    return render_to_response('galleries/index.html',{'albums':album_list},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Maybe i am over complicating this, and maybe some one can help me get thru this.

10x,
Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without tryiung to change your queries, I suggest to use a list of `(album, photo)` [tuples](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) instead of a long list:

```
for album in albums:
    album_list.append((album, Photo.objects.filter(album=album).order_by('?')[0]))
```

now use

```
    {{ for album, photo in album_list }}
```

(And be sure to check what happens if there are 0 photos in the album.)

Comment: Thank you, i am having a problem getting the actual image form that now into the IMG tag, but this another issue that i need to solve, but as for the question, this is working :-)

Comment: If i can, About the other things, when i do assert false on album_list I can see that i am getting ([Album, [<Photo:...>]), so i am getting the photo as a list, but a list of one object, how can get an object out of it, like the album, or how can u use the list of one photo in the template without using a for loop to iterate over it? 10x

Comment: Did you forget the [:1] at the end of the query?  better post this as a new question.

Comment: No, i didn't, left it just the same, I will post a new on, 10x :-)

Comment: Oops, this of course should be `[0]` and not `[:1]`.  BTW, you could have used `photo.0` for accessing the first item in the list without a `{{for}}`.  I am updating the answer above for future visitors.

Comment: 10x Udi, I got it in the other post, the solution is also over there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484743/trying-to-create-a-tuple-of-objects-create-an-object-and-a-queryset , 10x :-)